# Keep object rotation based on parent/other object coordinate system in Three.js?

Tags: rotation, coordinates, three.js, transform, webgl

I'm trying to keep the rotation of the child object the same as it was before being added to a parent (which is the camera).

I'm using Three.js' `worldToLocal` to keep position but the rotation changes because of the parent's position and rotation.

**Before** and **after** "pick up":
[image: Screenshot of the cube before pickup.] [image: Screenshot of the cube after pickup, position is the same but rotation changed.]

Notice on how the cube keeps position (thanks to `worldToLocal`) but the rotation changes.

**Edit:** I want to be able to set the initial rotation of the cube the same it had before being added to a parent. After that I want the child to act normally and rotate/translate like the parent does.

Comment: It sounds like you want to move/translate the child object along with it's parent, but not rotate it. I suppose you could subclass Object3D and overwrite a few functions so it would ignore rotation, but you could also quickly cheat wither either using an array of objects that are 'grouped' but not nested using .add or simply updating just the position of the 'child' manually from it's parent including the offset in the update loop. HTH

Comment: Oh, no, I want the child object to translate and rotate with the parent. I just want the initial rotation to be the same as the one it had before. Similar as if you were to pick a object and start carrying it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove a child from a scene and add it to a new parent, while maintaining the child's world position and orientation, do this:

```
parent.attach( child );
```

Note: If the `parent` is the `camera`, you have to remember to add the camera to the scene:

```
scene.add( camera );
```

It is currently not a requirement that the camera is part of the scene.

three.js r.109

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! `worldToLocal` code got me confused, I just needed to apply the inverse matrixWorld of the parent on the child.